# Problematic bc calculation in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, arithmetic, bc, floating-point

On Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit LTS I am writing a shell script and if I define the start of the `sequence` used in the `for loop` with a **variable** instead of a **constant** I get really weird behavior and there are lots of errors from the `bc` calculator. You can run the following code snippet to reproduce the errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
S=0.030
F=0.150
N=30
DIFF=`echo $F - $S | bc -l`
dw=`echo $DIFF / $N | bc -l`
is=`echo $S / $dw | bc -l`
if=`echo $F / $dw | bc -l`
for i in `seq $is $if` 
    do
        w=`echo "scale=3; $i * $dw" | bc -l`
done
```

If I change the start of the sequence to a constant it works perfectly, but when it is a variable there are problems the output is as follows:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
...
...
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

What may be the reason behind this behaviour? I would like to receive your suggestions and comments.

Comment: I ran your program with `bash 4.3.30(1)-release`  , i didn't prevent with any error.

Comment: Hmm the following is my Bash version but the problem persists it is really weird. `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Please wait until i test with dash.

Comment: Okay I am here.

Comment: dash doesn't report any problem....

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh This is pretty interesting I do not know why it is problematic in my case. Can I upgrade `bash` easily?

Comment: I don't see the issue and I am using Bash 4.3.11(1)-release as well. The `seq` is working properly as well as the `bc`.  @Vesnog, have you narrowed down which statement is causing the syntax error (add `set -x` to the beginning of the script)?

Comment: `apt-get install bash`

Comment: However, i prefer to corssplatform coding....

Comment: So use perl, python or ruby ?!

Comment: @Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh I implemented the operations in a different way and it worked. By the way is there a method to set the number of digits after the decimal point and get rid of the zero in front of the (to the left of) the decimal point?

Comment: @Vesnog Check out `length` and `scale` in [`bc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bc.1.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the decimal point separator in my Ubuntu installation was set to `,` (comma) instead of `.` (dot). I changed it with the following command:

```
sudo update-locale LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

And the problem was resolved.

Comment: Put `export LC_NUMERIC=C` at the start of your script, that way it'll be robust against the system configuration.

Comment: @Gilles Okay so what will C do in this case?

Comment: `C` means “use default settings” (so `.` as the decimal separator, etc.). Setting it explicitly in your script overrides whatever the environment might have set.

Comment: By redefining the environmental variable, right?